# Find optimal rigid transformation under constraint

Tags: python, algorithm, image-processing, computer-vision

I have a set of points `p` and I need to transform them so that the they align with another given set of points `q` (find the transform `T` from source to target).

So far it is an easy problem. My problem is that I do have some freedom aligning these points i.e, I only have to keep the alignment error below some given threshold (alpha) and not minimize the distance. I want to exploit this alignment freedom to minimize distances between `p` and a different set of points `r`. I marked the vectors to be optimized `E = Tp - r`

So basically I want to use the first alignment as a hard constraint and try to minimize another set of correspondences (I attached a picture). I want to minimize `|E|` (the green distances) under the constraint that the black points are within the red circles (alpha) after applying the transformation `T`.
[image]

I tried some heuristic solutions like calculating the maximum allowed rotation around the centroid and only then taking the maximum allowed translation but none of these solutions guarantee the optimal solution.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard about Lagrange optimization?
Here's the corresponding [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier).

You minimize a cost function (in your case E) under certain inequality
constraints and equality constraints (in your case no equality constraints).
This may be an approach for your solution?

Step 1:

Build augmented cost function: `E - L * (Tp - q - alpha)`

Step 2:

Find partial derivatives w.r.t `T` and `L`

Step 3:

Solve for zeros in partial derivatives

Comment: What makes the constraint an inequality one? Also, you haven't use the fact that I'm minimizing a scalar function and not a vector one (minimize the norm). Should I calculate the norms and differentiate the result?

Comment: Your Norm(Tp - q) < alpha equation is an inequality equation (which makes it an inequality constraint). Your function is a vector function (assuming p and q are vectors?) Sorry for the mistake in the augmented cost function: It should be Norm(E) - L * (Norm(Tp - q) - alpha).  Then you calculate the partial derivatives.

Comment: Thanks,I hope differentiating the norm is simple. About the inequality, what is unclear to me is how to implement it being an inequality one rather than equality. In both cases you use `-L * f(T)` where `f(T)` is the constraint?

Comment: The inequality constraint must be in the form g <= 0 (where g is your inequality constraint function). So in your case the constraint is + L * (Norm(Tp - q) - alpha). Note the plus instead of the minus, sorry I think I wrote it the other way in my original answer. Here another link that contains an explicit example with inequality constraints. https://people.duke.edu/~hpgavin/cee201/LagrangeMultipliers.pdf